# Refatoração de função para recolher constantes com determinado prefixo

Tags: php, refatoração, funções

Tenho uma função a funcionar que visa localizar e agrupar numa matriz as constantes que estão declaradas correspondendo a um determinado prefixo:

### Função:

```php
function get_constantsByPrefix($prefix) {

  foreach (get_defined_constants() as $key=>$value) {
    if (substr($key,0,strlen($prefix))==$prefix) {
      $dump[$key] = $value;
    }
  }

  if (empty($dump)) {
    return "Atenção: Não foram localizadas constantes com o prefixo '".$prefix."'";
  } else {
    return $dump;
  }
}
```

### Exemplo de utilização:

```php
print_r(get_constantsByPrefix('CON_WEBSITE_'));
```

### Saída:

```php
Array ( [CON_WEBSITE_01] => John [CON_WEBSITE_02] => Doe )
```

Esta função faz uso da função de PHP [get_defined_constants()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-constants.php) para apurar todas as constantes declaradas e a partir desse resultado, verificar quais as que correspondem ao prefixo indicado.
Se encontrar, adiciona para uma matriz, devolvendo no final uma matriz com as constantes localizadas ou uma mensagem de aviso caso não tenham sido localizadas nenhumas.

## Questão:

É possível optimizar esta função permitindo uma redução de código e/ou ganho de eficiência na sua execução?

Comment: Você está experimentando problemas de performance? Qual a sua motivação para otimizar? À primeira vista me parece uma função concisa e sem nenhum problema grave de eficiência ou pontos passíveis de melhora.

Comment: @mgibsonbr Para já não tenho nenhum problema em particular, mas sim, preocupa-me a performance pois a função é utilizada na nossa área administrativa que após implementação vai servir centenas de pessoas, ao mesmo tempo que irá conter um número exorbitante de constantes.

Comment: Todavia, o principal motivo é a prática de submeter à comunidade novas funções que uso ou crio para recolher feedback e/ou melhoramentos (_normalmente alguém pensa em algo que eu não pensei ou previ_) :)

Comment: Entendi. Perguntei porque não tenho muito a sugerir, não, a menos que o próprio `get_defined_constants` esteja lento (e aí, na ausência de um meio alternativo, só restaria usar uma cache - ordenada de preferência, de modo que uma busca binária possa ser utilizada para evitar percorrer a lista toda).

Comment: @bigown Nada ainda em relação às tags, melhor esperarmos o ok do Marc Gravell. Por enquanto cedilha só funciona no meta.

Answer (score 4):

Sei que não estou exatamente respondendo a pergunta, pois parece desejar especificamente uma melhora em performance, mas gostaria de fazer algumas sugestões para melhorar a clareza do código.

Da forma como está, pode-se dizer que a função está fazendo "coisas demais": ela verifica que existe constantes **E** cria uma mensagem para o usuário -- são dois assuntos diferentes, pode não ser interessante estarem ligados.

Como o nome da função é `get_constantsByPrefix()`, é razoável assumir que ela devolverá uma lista de constantes (afinal, é `get_constants()` e não `get_constants_or_error_message()`). Por isso, fica melhor devolver uma lista vazia quando não encontrar nenhuma constante para o prefixo.

Por isso, sugiro remover o if/else do final e retornar o `$dump` direto. =)

Dessa forma, quando você escrever o código cliente (isto é, o código que chama a função) não precisará ter que lembrar de verificar o tipo da variável retornada para saber se existem constantes. E caso deseje mostrar uma mensagem para o usuário bastará verificar se a lista está vazia. =)

Comment: Sim, faz todo o sentido que a mensagem seja trabalhada fora da função, a função, como o próprio nome indica, é mesmo para recolher uma matriz, vazia ou com dados!

Answer (score 0):

Aproveitando o gancho do @elias, se a não existência de constantes for algo grave na sua aplicação, uma alternativa mais consistente ao *retorno de mensagens de erro* em funções é o uso de exceções, assim:

```php
if (empty($dump)) 
    throw new Exception("Atenção: Não foram localizadas constantes com o prefixo '".$prefix."'");
```

Entretanto, caso seja apenas algo informativo, faça um log da mensagem e retorne uma lista vazia.

Além disso, considere também o *princípio da responsabilidade única* e, dependendo da serventia dessa mensagem, coloque esse `if` no código "cliente", que chama o método. Veja um exemplo:

```php
define('CON_WEBSITE_01', 'John');
(...)
$constants = get_constantsByPrefix('CON_WEBSITE_');
print_r( empty($constants) ? "Nada encontrado" :  $constants );
```

---

Quanto ao desempenho da função `get_constantsByPrefix()`, dependendo do caso de uso dela, podemos considerar os seguintes fatores:

#### As constantes podem ser definidas no "meio" da execução principal do sistema ou geralmente elas são definidas na inicialização, por exemplo, em inclusão de classes no início do script?

Dependendo do caso, valeria a pena armazenar o mapa de retorno para uso posterior, ao invés de sempre iterar sobre todas as constantes.

Vamos rabiscar um exemplo usando uma classe:

```php
class Constants {

    private $constant_map = null;

    public static function listByPrefix($prefix) {

        if ($this->constant_map == null) {
            $this->constant_map = array();
            foreach (get_defined_constants() as $key=>$value) {
                if (substr($key,0,strlen($prefix))==$prefix) {
                    $this->constant_map[$key] = $value;
                }
            }
        }

        if (empty($this->constant_map)) {
            throw new Exception("Atenção: Não foram localizadas constantes com o prefixo '".$prefix."'");
        } else {
            return $this->constant_map;
        }

    }

}
```

Exemplo de uso:

```php
define('CON_WEBSITE_01', 'John');
Constants::listByPrefix('CON_WEBSITE_');
```

#### Você tem o controle sobre a definição das constantes?

Neste caso, você poderia encapsular a criação delas com uma função que já as armazene no mapa.

Outro esboço:

```php
class Constants {

    private $constant_map = array();

    public static function define($key, $value) {
        
        define($key);
        $this->constant_map[$key] = $value;
        
    }

    public static function listByPrefix($prefix) {

        if (empty($this->constant_map)) {
            throw new Exception("Atenção: Não foram localizadas constantes com o prefixo '".$prefix."'");
        } else {
            return $this->constant_map;
        }

    }

}
```

Exemplo de uso:

```php
Constants::define('CON_WEBSITE_01', 'John');
Constants::listByPrefix('CON_WEBSITE_');
```

Comment: É meio estranho uma função de listagem levantar uma exceção caso não encontrar nada. Como você já descreveu, a única maneira de evitar a exceção ser lançada será garantir que existem constantes para o prefixo dado -- o que pode ser exatamente o que o código chamador quer descobrir. Exceções ficam melhores para comportamentos realmente excepcionais. Mas concordo que, fosse outro caso, usar exceções seria uma maneira mais conveniente de sinalizar o erro.

Comment: Concordo que *na maioria dos casos* é estranho e a melhor alternativa é retornar uma lista vazia ou mesmo nulo, embora alguns argumentem contra retornar `null`. Mas depende do que isso significa dentro aplicação, se é um erro grave ou apenas algum tipo de informação para log. Se o retorno dessa lista for essencial para a aplicação, como uma constante de acesso a banco de dados, por exemplo, então o fato de não encontrar nada é motivo de falha. Mas eu também concordo que seria melhor tratar isso fora da função.

Comment: @elias Obrigado pela comentário. Editei a resposta para tentar não deixar confusão.

Answer (score 0):

Sugestão para redução de código (já retirando a mensagem de aviso sugerida pelo @elias):

```php
function get_constantsByPrefix($prefix) {
  foreach (get_defined_constants() as $key=>$value) {
    if($prefix == "" || strpos($key, $prefix) === 0) $dump[$key] = $value;
  }
 return $dump;
}
```

---

PS: Não fiz um *benchmarking* de performance.

PS2: Colocada também a consistência para retornar todas as constantes, caso `$prefix` venha vazio (se você quiser utilizar a mesma função para todas as situações).